# File not posting in form submission

Tags: html, forms, file, file-upload

I have a form that I cannot seem to figure out why the file is not posting.

It seems like this should be fairly straight forward but it seems to kick my butt.

I'm using the PHPmailer plugin.

I get all the other fields and I get the email but the file is never included because it never posts.

Form code.

```html
<form id="bookrelease" name="bookrelease" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-m-6 col-lg-6">
      <p class="startdate">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input id="startdate" name="startdate" type='text' class='inputspecial form-fixed-height' placeholder="&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;Start Date">
          <span class="input-group-addon calendarbtn">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar calendarbtn2"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <label for="startdate" id="startdateLb"><span class="error">*Start date required.</span>
        </label>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-m-6 col-lg-6">
      <p class="enddate">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
          <input id="enddate" name="enddate" type='text' class='inputspecial form-fixed-height' placeholder="&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;End Date">
          <span class="input-group-addon calendarbtn">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar calendarbtn2"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <label for="enddate" id="enddateLb"><span class="error">*End date required.</span>
        </label>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-m-6 col-lg-6">
      <p class="BRauthorname">
        <input class="form-fixed-height" type="text" id="BRauthorname" name="BRauthorname" placeholder="Author Name">
        <label for="BRauthorname" id="BRauthornameLb"><span class="error">*Author name required</span>
        </label>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-m-6 col-lg-6">
      <p class="ABRemail">
        <input class="form-fixed-height" type="email" id="ABRemail" name="ABRemail" placeholder="Author Email">
        <label for="ABRemail" id="ABRemail-1Lb"><span class="error error1">*Email Field Required</span>
        </label>
        <label for="ABRemail" id="ABRemail-2Lb"><span class="error error2">*Email Not Valid</span>
        </label>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-m-6 col-lg-6">
      <p class="booktitle">
        <input class="form-fixed-height" type="text" id="booktitle" name="booktitle" placeholder="Book Title">
        <label for="booktitle" id="booktitleLb"><span class="error">*Book title required</span>
        </label>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-m-6 col-lg-6">
      <p class="authorwebsite">
        <input class="form-fixed-height optional" type="url" id="authorwebsite" name="authorwebsite" placeholder="Author Web Site - optional">
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-m-6 col-lg-6">
      <p class="sellerssite">
        <input class="form-fixed-height" type="url" id="sellerssite" name="sellerssite" placeholder="Book Retailer's Web Address">
        <label for="sellerssite" id="sellerssiteLb"><span class="error">*Book retailer's web address required</span>
        </label>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-m-6 col-lg-6">
      <p class='booktype'>
        <input class="form-fixed-height optional" type="text" id="booktype" name="booktype" placeholder="Format(s) - optional">
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-m-6 col-lg-6">
      <p class="genre">
        <input class="form-fixed-height optional" type="text" id="genre" name="genre" placeholder="Genre(s) - optional">
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-m-6 col-lg-6">
      <p class="fixedheight">
        <input class="file form-fixed-height" id="BRfile" type="file" name="BRfile" data-preview-file-type="image" />
        <label for="BRfile" id="BRfileLb"><span class="error">*opps! invalid file. Only jpeg and png files accepted</span>
        </label>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <div id="ErrResults">
      <!-- Error Here -->
    </div>
    <div id="MainResult">
      <!-- Response Here -->
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="contact-btn bookrelease-btn">Send Message</a>
    <input type="submit" value="BRfile" class="contact-btn bookrelease-btn">
  </div>
</form>
```

PHP code where I look for the file but it evaluates to false.

```html
    if (array_key_exists($_POST['postBRfile'], $_FILES)) {
            // First handle the upload
            // Don't trust provided filename - same goes for MIME types
            // See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004 for more thorough upload validation
            $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES[$_POST['postBRfile']]['name']));
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$_POST['postBRfile']]['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
                $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file');
            }
 
    }
```

Comment: What is `$_POST['postBRfile']`?

Comment: The name of your input-file is `BRfile`, so you should use `$_FILES['BRfile']`. I don't know what (and if) you have inside `$_POST['postBRfile']`, but if it's not `BRfile` your code will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand `postBRfile`

try this.

```
if (array_key_exists($_POST['BRfile'], $_FILES)) {
        // First handle the upload
        // Don't trust provided filename - same goes for MIME types
        // See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004 for more thorough upload validation
        $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES[$_POST['BRfile']]['name']));
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$_POST['BRfile']]['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file');
        }

}
```

Comment: So I realized that I forgot that I had a jquery file doing client-side validation and that may be where the issue is. I am trying to dig through the code to verify.

Comment: Feel free to put the issue

Comment: so far I am unable to get the file to upload so for now I have commented out the code as it was holding up the project and not an essential part that I will revisit after go live as an upgrade.